# cannot set value as a string instead of object in multiple selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select for autocomplete and option related field. In single selection the below code works for only sending the value as string but in multiple it does not work though it works if i want the value as object.

Here is the code

```
const normalizedValue = (input, options, valueType, isMulti) => {
  if (valueType === "string" && !isMulti) {
    options.find(option => option.value === input.value);
  }
  if (valueType === "string" && isMulti) {
    console.log("input value", input);
    options.filter(option => option.value === input.value);
  }

  if (valueType === "object" && !isMulti) {
    options.find(option => option === input.value);
  }

  if (valueType === "object" && isMulti) {
    options.filter(option => option === input.value);
  }
};

const SearchableTextField = ({
  children,
  input,
  options,
  isMulti,
  valueType,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <Select
      {...props}
      clearable={props.clearable}
      searchable={props.searchable}
      options={options}
      {...input}
      value={normalizedValue(input, options, valueType, isMulti)}
      onChange={option =>
        valueType === "string"
          ? input.onChange(option.value)
          : input.onChange(option)
      }
      onBlur={() => input.onBlur(input.value)}
      isMulti={isMulti}
    />
  );
};

const MyForm = reduxForm({ form: "MyForm" })(
  class extends React.PureComponent {
    handleSubmit(values) {
      console.log("values", values);
    }
    render() {
      const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
      return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit.bind(this))}>
          <Field
            name="myCoolSelect"
            component={SearchableTextField}
            options={[
              { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
              { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
              { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
            ]}
            valueType="string"
            isMulti
          />
          <button type="submit">SUbmit</button>
        </form>
      );
    }
  }
);
```

If i have the options as following

```
options = [
 {value: 'abc', label: 'ABC'},
 {value: 'abc2', label: 'ABC2'},
]
```

the expected output when i select suppose first option is selectedOption: "abc" in single selection which works and in multiple it should be selectedOption: ["abc", "abc2"] (this is not working)

I have a reproducible code as well in sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/wnvpnlj245

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
  onChange={option =>
    valueType === "string"
      ? input.onChange(option.value)
      : input.onChange(option)
  }
```

You need also check here if its multi or not. Because when its multi it pass value as array.

Try like

```
 onChange={option => {
    valueType === "string"
      ? input.onChange(isMulti ? option.map(o => o.value) : option.value)
      : input.onChange(option)
    }
  }
```